Why the Riesz multiplier is a Fourier multiplier?
I have a doubt about Fourier multipliers.
Definition. A function $m\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{C}$ essentially bounded ($m\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$) is a Fourier multiplier for $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if the operator $T_m\colon \mathcal{S}\subset L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\to L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ defined by $T_m(u)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(m(\xi)\widehat{u}(\xi)\right)$ is bounded.
Question: Why is $\xi\mapsto -i\frac{\xi_j}{|\xi|}$ (Riesz multiplier) a Fourier multiplier if this function is not bounded at origin?

It is bounded by $1$ on $\Bbb{R}^n\setminus {0}$, so it belongs to $L^{\infty}(\Bbb{R}^n)$.

oh right! thanks

This implies that the definition of Fourier multiplier must be corrected by $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \left{0\right}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

No. You’re forgetting the most basic thing about Lebesgue measure and integration: we only need things to be a.e defined (in most cases).

This mean that $\int_{|\xi|\leq R}\frac{\xi_j}{|\xi|},d\xi$ is finite because the set $\left{\xi\colon \xi=0\right}$ has meazure zero?
